# Unable to activate and use Anaconda Keras / TensorFlow environment

Tags: anaconda

I have been using an Anaconda environment for the past few weeks to train my model. But suddenly today I am unable to activate it. I usually activate and update packages from the Anaconda prompt. I am attaching a screenshot, which I captured which disappears after the warning message. Is anyone else facing the same issue?

[image: Anaconda prompt screenshot]

Comment: Thank You Anaksunaman for correcting my question. Henceforth I will keep in mind about using the right Caps for keywords.

Answer (score 1):

In my Anaconda environment I was using python 3.7, It seems that TensorFlow does not currently support Python 3.7. so I created another environment with python 3.6 and installed specific versions of tensorflow (1.12.0)and keras(2.1.6). Now my environment is working again normally as it should. Thanks all for reading and considering my question. Any other feedback would be welcome.